Visual Studio Code shows strange text
I opened the Visual Studio Code to code and it (VSC) showed like the image below. I was opening (in the previous time) a workspace.
I tried to reopen, ctrl+r many times, change workspace, restart computer but it still can't fix the error. Sometimes, after ctrl+r, it may appear the GUI in the corner (not full window) (the second image is when I tried to press ctrl+r


In the previous picture — because I've captured the selected window — not because that window is in fullscreen mode, above is the new one.
I also tried to reset settings.json (by go to the file, in the tutorial in the comments, and edit the content to {}).

You appear to be running in a type of fullscreen mode, so press F11 and see if it exits that. Also, follow the instructions here to check your settings.json: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108515/how-to-reset-settings-in-visual-studio-code

@music2myear because i captured the window, i'm not in a fullscreen mode, also, I've reset the settings.json file but it not worked

Windows can be captured when they are fullscreen. What have you reset in the settings.json? Please add that info to the main question. Perhaps backup your VS Code profile and reinstall? A tip: editing your post is strongly encouraged here. Comments are more for us to ask you questions; you can actually answer by editing your post, and the benefit of that is that your main post gets better, clearer, more complete, or just shows the process(es) you've done so far. This makes it so that others don't have to comb through comments to understand your situation fully.

Thanks for your recommendation, I've edited the post!

that appears to be the css stylesheets for the editor itself. I think a little clarity on what "it showed like" means (i.e. what and where "it" refers to, does this happen when opening any code file, does the GUI show up or it's just this and nothing else etc

Solution shouldn't be part of the question, but rather a comment or an answer.

Finally, after many unsuccessful ways, I decided to reinstall Visual Studio Code (without uninstall it, ig to avoid losing data) and it back to normal now!
